# What actions in Outlook would cause PR_LAST_MODIFIER_NAME or PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME to be modified?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, mapi

I am testifying soon as to data I gathered using MFCMAPI in which I determined that the PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME did not match the PR_CREATION_TIME or PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME of the message.

What actions in Outlook would cause PR_LAST_MODIFIER_NAME or PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME to be modified? Simply reading, marking the message as unread, and viewing the attachments does not modify these properties in my lab tests.

I am trying to determine what other actions performed by the user or on behalf of the user could cause the PR_LAST_MODIFIER_NAME to no longer list the sender and PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME no longer match Delivery/Creation time.

I had the opportunity many months ago to talk to developer on the MFCMAPI project from Microsoft and I am kicking myself in the gut for not writing down his name.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean Steve Griffin?

I am not him, but I think I can easily answer your question - every time IMessage::SaveChanges is called, PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME will be reset.

Comment: That is a helpful start and will give me another path to go down searching for results. You wouldn't happen to know the type of actions call IMessage:SaveChanges from within Outlook 2010 or an ActiveSync client.

Comment: Also it was not Steve Griffin, it was someone who worked on MFCMAPI  after Steve handed it off to the Exchange team to be turned into a end-user tool.

Comment: It can be Outlook itself (save and autosave), third-party addin, or, in case of Exchange, some other user saving the message from another machine.

Comment: From what I know, Steve is the only developer - https://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/wikipage/history

Comment: I only know what the developer told me when I worked with him on an Exchange Online issue we were experiencing. From this article, Steve handed it to the Microsoft Exchange team for a while who helped him mature it for use by end users and then later took it back and turned it in to what it is today.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2008/01/04/a-brief-history-of-mfcmapi.aspx

Comment: I'm the only developer ever on MFCMAPI (except for one feature Jason Johnston wrote). But I did have a sponsor on the Exchange dev team during that time they officially owned it. That may have been who you were talking to.

Comment: Expanding more on Dmitry's answer, you'll note that marking the message as read did not count as modification. That's because you use **SetReadFlag** to set the read flag, and this doesn't involve SaveChanges.